# jquery resizable: respect width/height of inner/outer elements to not overflow

Tags: jquery-ui-resizable

Is it possible to resize element with respect to childs/parents? I can easily resize element width to zero, so childs overflow, which is bad (for me). Has jquery some behaviour for this to prevent?

One solution is bind to resize() event, get position/size of inner elements and check if (child.width + child.left < parent.width). But in this case i don't know how to tell jquery to not resize more, only back.

There is also another view from resizing element to his parent, but it could be the same. Check element siblings if one of them overflow parent.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Do you have any code examples that demonstrate the problem you're facing?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I make an example http://jsfiddle.net/3vtur/1/

Comment: Because blue DIVs has fixed size (has some content, i can't make smaller), when i resize red (via jquery-resizable) to 100px, one of childs overflow. I would like to catch this situation and block resizing.

I general i know what to calculate (asked higher), but don't know if it is good way, or if jquery has for this allready.

Situation is more complicated, red element has also some siblings and parents (more structured document).

Answer (score 0):

The minWidth and minHeight options might be used for the children, and the maxWidth and maxHeight options or the containment option - for the parent.